# Why does Chrome cause this border / bleed around this image when using translate?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uy6yhv4d/1/

I have an `img` with `background-color: red` set.

When rendered on the page normally, without using transform, it appears as expected, with no red border.

However, when I `trasform: translate` it for positioning, the red background now "bleeds" the edges, causing a red border to appear.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This *may* be caused by browser rounding of Fractional Pixels. As to why it only occurs when you apply the `transform` property well...that's way over my head.  [This](http://cruft.io/static/rounding/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: I think this happens, because images cant be stretched to widths with point numbers.. If you add a div around the image and set there the objevit-cover / contain value - it would fit perfectly : )

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner @I haz kode I think the fractions are only part of it. Even if you removed them, you still get a red border on mobile in that fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/778oaqLq/

Ive made a new fiddle with a some changes to the styling. With this methode the red border isnt visible.

Browser's itself cant stretch the images, because the images with point numbers get rounded.. (as written in the first comment of this post).

Answer (score 1):

The red border is coming from the `background-color: red;`. I found that removing the point values from the dimensions removed the appearance of a red border:

```
img {
  height: 256px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think the fractions are only part of it. Even if you removed them, you still get a red border on mobile in that fiddle.